# Multivariate differences between groups controlling for one factor (MANOVA)

Tags: r, hypothesis-testing, multivariate-analysis, manova

I have a sample of 100 participants who have scores on 5 different variables (V1-V5). Some participants took part in a workshop, others did not. 
I am interested in investigating the influence of workshop participation and gender on the scores of variables. For gender and workshop participation significant differences where shown (see below). My data looks the following:

```
  V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 gender workshop
1  2  2  5  5  4   male      yes
2  4  3  4  3  3 female      yes
3  3  5  5  3  1 female      yes
4  1  5  5  5  1 female      yes
5  5  2  2  4  5 female       no
6  5  4  5  1  7   male      yes
...
```

Here is what I did:

**MANOVA**

```
library (car)

DV <- as.matrix(x[, 1:5])
output = lm(DV ~ gender*workshop, data = x, contrasts=list(gender = contr.sum, workshop = contr.sum))
manova_out = Manova(output, type = "III")
summary (manova_out, multivariate = T)


Multivariate Tests: gender
                 Df test stat approx F num Df den Df  Pr(>F)  
Pillai            1 0.1336421 2.838336      5     92 0.01983 *
Wilks             1 0.8663579 2.838336      5     92 0.01983 *
Hotelling-Lawley  1 0.1542574 2.838336      5     92 0.01983 *
Roy               1 0.1542574 2.838336      5     92 0.01983 *
---
Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1


Multivariate Tests: workshop
                 Df test stat approx F num Df den Df   Pr(>F)  
Pillai            1 0.0967188 1.970179      5     92 0.090415 .
Wilks             1 0.9032812 1.970179      5     92 0.090415 .
Hotelling-Lawley  1 0.1070749 1.970179      5     92 0.090415 .
Roy               1 0.1070749 1.970179      5     92 0.090415 .
---
Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1


Multivariate Tests: gender:workshop
                 Df test stat  approx F num Df den Df  Pr(>F)
Pillai            1 0.0242859 0.4579838      5     92 0.80649
Wilks             1 0.9757141 0.4579838      5     92 0.80649
Hotelling-Lawley  1 0.0248904 0.4579838      5     92 0.80649
Roy               1 0.0248904 0.4579838      5     92 0.80649
```

Workshop participation appears to have a significant effect on the scores of variables.

#### My questions:

**Is this effect maybe just due to the larger amount of females in the sample? 
How can I make sure that my significant results for workshop participation are only due to workshop participation and not gender? Is there a way of controlling for gender?**

Would checking for an interaction effect between gender and workshop be useful? Is a MANOVA be the right method in that case? But what would the MANOVA results tell me?  And to what extend are my results influenced by the different amount of females/males and workshop participants/not workshop participants?

#### For replication

**My data**

```
library (dplyr)
set.seed(2)
n <- 100
x <- replicate(5, sample(1:5, n, rep=T))
colnames(x) <- paste0("V", 1:5)
x <- as.data.frame(x)
x$gender <- sample(c("male", "female"), n, prob=c(.4, .6), rep=T)
x$workshop <- sample(c("yes", "no"), n, rep=T)
x[x$workshop == "yes", 1:5] = 
    x[x$workshop == "yes", 1:5] + sample(0:1, 100, rep=T, prob=c(.9, .1))
x[x$gender == "male", 1:5] = 
    x[x$gender == "male", 1:5] + sample(0:1, 100, rep=T, prob=c(.9, .1))

x$workshop <- as.factor(x$workshop)
x$gender <- as.factor(x$gender)
```

Comment: (1) The imbalance between females and males does not affect the conclusions. (2) You are *already* "controlling for gender" by including it into the model. The workshop participation effect is not due to gender. (3) MANOVA is a reasonable approach in your situation. (4) You **do not** have a "significant effect" of workshop participation ($p=0.09$), unless you are willing to work with $0.1$ significance threshold which is a VERY WEAK standard of evidence.

Comment: `gender` effect is the difference between the genders, averaged across the workshops. `workshop` effect is the difference between the workshops, averaged across the genders. So these are controlled, not marginal, effects. Additional interaction effect estimates whether the workshop effect varies for the two genders (and vice versa). If a 2-factor design is balanced interaction effect cannot contaminate the two main effects.

Comment: Note also you are using type III SS. Under it, only non-contaminated portions of the three effects are being drawn, this is the most "universal" approach as it tests for the same hypotheses irrespective of (un)balancedness of a design.

Comment: Would there be any difference between a MANOVA as outlined above and a MANCOVA when a factor (here `gender`) is regarded as the covariate and one is interested in the effect of workshop only?

Comment: @Mark A covariate in MANCOVA is usually understood to be continuous, not categorical. If it is categorical (like here), then it is MANOVA.

Answer (score 0):

I would expand the analysis to include a multivariate regression analysis. MANOVA tests for statistical significance, but to answer the question you are interested in (influence of workshop participation and gender on the scores of variables) it will be more helpful to look at effect sizes together with significance levels. A significance level alone does not tell you how much the workshop or gender influence the scores. Having effect sizes together with a p-values, alternatively confidence intervals, would give you the opportunity to judge both the influence and uncertainty of the effect.

The analysis would control for both gender and workshop. If you have reason to believe that males or females should get a better effect of the workshop, it could be worth including an interaction effect.

Here is an example with more explanation (in STATA, but should be easily translated to R):
http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/stata/dae/mvreg.htm

Comment: Welcome Hav, your answer currently only partially answers the OP's question. Can you expand upon it? Maybe give an example of how effect size matter (over significance)?